# Spring roo: addon 'typicalsecurity' was found but currently not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

I'm trying to use the typicalsecurity addon in spring roo [here](https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-typical-security/wiki/GettingStarted). 
But I keep getting an error `Command 'typicalsecurity setup' was found but is not currently available`
Other times I get this

```
Command 'typicalsecurity setup' not found (for assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
Located add-on that may offer this command
1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 - Y 1.3.1.RELEASE This is an Addon which helps developer quick setup...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
```

After searching all I could found is [this](https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-typical-security/issues/detail?id=17), but it didn't work for me as well

I tried using `security setup` and it worked, but without email verification and sign up as in `typicalsecurit`, and I need both in my application.

I can't understand where the problem is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This add-on nowadays is included as part of [gvNIX project](http://www.gvnix.org/en/index.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the example application has no signup functionality nor email verification.

Comment: The example doesn't uses typicalsecurity but this is included in project. Try to download and use it. This is a script used to test the add-on on CI: https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix/blob/master/addon-web-mvc-typicalsecurity/src/main/resources/typicalsecurity.roo

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm having only a problem sending the verification email, but I think it is because of the email.properties. I'll check it and return to you if I couldn't fix it.